# Confusion About PFE Calculation and XVA Pricing Engine's Exclusive Reliance on Parameter Simulation

Tags: monte-carlo, pricing, simulations, bootstrapping, xva

Potential Future Exposure (a credit risk metric) is calculated using
$$PFE(\tau) = \text{max}\Big(0, \mathcal{P}_{derivative}(\tau) - CVA(\tau)\Big)$$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the price / fair value / TV / MtM of derivative instrument; and $CVA$ is Credit Valuation Adjustment.

I am looking inside an XVA Pricing Engine (that does the derivative pricing and then spits out PFE), and **all** the parameters are obtained by simulation; when I search PFE calculations material online, all also imply that pricing of $\mathcal{P}$ has to be done using Monte Carlo simulation (which to me means the same as simulating your parameters).

I don't fully get why -- you can have market implied / bootstrapped forward curves for rates, inflation, volatility, default probability -- so you can calculate $\mathcal{P}$ (and by extension $PFE$ not just for $t=0$, but any time period in the future. The only circumstances simulating parameters using Heston, Hull-White, Garman-Kohlagen, Jarrow-Yildirim woul kind of make sense to me is if you needed to price some exotic derivatives that don't have closed for solutions -- and then -- said -- eh, I might as well just have consistency and price everything by simulation in my C++ Pricing Engine.

Could someone please help explain.

Comment: $PFE(t)$ is a percentile (say 99th) of a price distribution of the portfolio of derivatives under consideration. Say your portfolio is an equity option and an interest rate swap and you want the PFE in 1 year from now: you need to simulate the equity dynamics and the rates dynamics, say you do the equity with GBM and the rate with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, with a correlation between the two: so your MC will do (say) 10,000 paths, each will contain a value of the rate and the equity. You price the equity option and the IRS on each path and the 99th percentile of the combined price is the PFE.

Comment: In other words, your formula for PFE is incorrect, the PFE is **not** the max of zero and the value of the derivative minus the CVA (by PFE, I mean Potential Future Exposure).